# Is it good or bad if I use laravel's before and after middleware for encrypt and decrypt every request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I am using two middlewares right now in my laravel api application one is before middleware that is for decrypt the incoming request and after middleware for encrypt the responses so is it good practice or not? Or any risk in this?

Comment: Could you explain why you do this, why not use TLS/SSL?

Comment: @marteen sorry I don't know what is TLS/SSL I am new to this.

Comment: Hmmm..... So you are new to this, but you are driving into encryption topics. That's a bit scary in terms of security. TLS/SSL you do know, it's active when you use https, secure http. It handles the machine to machine encryption for you.